# Combine two file according to a specific match

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have two big files in which each column is separated by a tab.

File1:

```
ID1 -5.1 -4.4
ID2 -6.2 -3.8
ID3 -8.9 -7.1
ID4 -14.6 -7.8
```

File2:

```
ID3 apple car joy block,use foo G27H1
ID1 juice mouse,elephant sad,lazy ill,safe bar F25B9
ID5 salt house,room end,thing,else common foobar A30B5,C76D3
```

What I want is a bash script that compares the two files according to column 1 and that appends column 2, 5 and 7 of File2 to File1 if a match is found, otherwise print 'NO MATCH' if no match is found. This is my expected output:

```
ID1 -5.1 -4.4 juice ill,safe F25B9
ID2 -6.2 -3.8 NO MATCH
ID3 -8.9 -7.1 apple block,use G27H1
ID4 -14.6 -7.8 NO MATCH
```

This is what I've tried:

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=($2,$5,$7);next} END { print($2 in a)} ($1 in a) {print $1,(a[$1])}' $file2 $file1`

but I can't understand what is wrong. Moreover the part of script regarding 'NO MATCH' is still missing.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: *`what is wrong`* ... it would be of benefit if you mentioned that your `awk` code generates a syntax error (and show the complete error)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to solve this:

```bash
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 " " $5 " " $7; next}
       {print $0, $1 in a ? a[$1] : "NO MATCH"}' file2 file1
ID1 -5.1 -4.4 juice ill,safe F25B9
ID2 -6.2 -3.8 NO MATCH
ID3 -8.9 -7.1 apple block,use G27H1
ID4 -14.6 -7.8 NO MATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using `join` to merge the records from the files (After sorting them):

```bash
$ join -t ' ' -a 1 -j 1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.5,2.7 -e 'NO MATCH' <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) | sed 's/\(NO MATCH *\)\{3\}$/NO MATCH/'
ID1 -5.1 -4.4 juice ill,safe F25B9
ID2 -6.2 -3.8 NO MATCH
ID3 -8.9 -7.1 apple block,use G27H1
ID4 -14.6 -7.8 NO MATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

The current code has a syntax issue related to how the 3 columns are assigned to the array:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=($2,$5,$7);next} END { print($2 in a)} ($1 in a) {print $1,(a[$1])}' file2 file1
awk: cmd. line:1: FNR==NR{a[$1]=($2,$5,$7);next} END { print($2 in a)} ($1 in a) {print $1,(a[$1])}
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ syntax error
```

After the syntax issue is fixed (eg, `a[$1] = $2 OFS $5 OFS $7`) there are several issues with the current code:

- when `$1 in a` the code prints the 1st field (`$1`) instead of the entire line (`$0`)
- there is no process block for rows where `$1 in a` is false, and therefore no attempt to append `NO MATCH` on the end of said lines
- the `END{...}` block is not needed since there is no requirement for post file processing (eg, printing a summary line, dumping the contents of memory, etc)

One `awk` idea for addressing the various issues:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2 OFS $5 OFS $7; next }      # append the fields with the output field separator (OFS)
        { ext="NO MATCH"                        # set a default extension
          if ($1 in a)                          # if we have a match in a[] then ...
             ext = a[$1]                        # redefine the extension
          print $0, ext                         # print current row plus extension
        }
' file2 file1
```

Consolidating the 2nd half into a single `print` while using the ternary operator:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { a[$1]=$2 OFS $5 OFS $7; next }
        { print $0, ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "NO MATCH") }
' file2 file1
```

Both of these generate:

```
ID1 -5.1 -4.4 juice ill,safe F25B9
ID2 -6.2 -3.8 NO MATCH
ID3 -8.9 -7.1 apple block,use G27H1
ID4 -14.6 -7.8 NO MATCH
```

**NOTES:**

- OP has mentioned the input files are tab delimited
- current input files appear to be single-space delimited
- the default input field separator (`FS` == white space) and output field separator (`OFS` == space) are sufficient to generate the expected output
- if the output needs to be tab delimited then the `awk` script needs to be updated to include this detail, eg: `BEGIN { OFS="\t" }` or `BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }`